# Own PreferencePage: Enable and disable FieldEditor by BooleanFieldEditor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm creating my own PreferencePage for Eclipse for a RCP application.
There is a FileFieldEditor which I want to be enabled and disabled by an BooleanFieldEditor.

Now I can't figure out how to implement this.

```
public class PreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements
IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

FileFieldEditor subversionPathEditor;
BooleanFieldEditor subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor;

public PreferencePage() {
super(GRID);
setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
setDescription(""); //$NON-NLS-1$
}


protected void createFieldEditors() {
subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor = new BooleanFieldEditor
    ("subversionSupport", "Enable Subversion support", BooleanFieldEditor.DEFAULT, getFieldEditorParent());
System.out.println(subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor.getPreferenceName());

subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor.setPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
    if ("field_editor_value".equalsIgnoreCase(event.getProperty())) {
        Boolean enabled = (Boolean)event.getNewValue();
        subversionPathEditor.setEnabled(enabled, getFieldEditorParent());
    }

    }
});
addField(subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor);
subversionPathEditor = new FileFieldEditor("SubversionPathEditor", "Subversion client executable: ", true, 
    FileFieldEditor.VALIDATE_ON_KEY_STROKE, getFieldEditorParent());
subversionPathEditor.setStringValue(VCSSettings.getSubversionPath());
    addField(subversionPathEditor);
```

Any ideas where to place the code to enable and disable the FileFieldEditor? I know how to enable/disable but in which method has the code to be placed?

Already tried in createFieldEditors(), checkState(), updateFieldEditors() and createControl().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the

```
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
{
  ... extra here

  super.propertyChange(event);
}
```

method of `FieldEditorPreferencePage` to get the property change events (for all the fields).

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the problem together with DirkNM's if-clause. Thank you too!

Comment: Is there no functionality in the field editor API to handle this automatically? It would be convenient to setup some field editors as children to a `OptionalFieldEditor` to have all children to automatically be enabled/disabled by their parent.

Comment: @Lii No, there is no such functionality